Issues with window.editorInstance.destroy() in CKEditor 5
I’m encountering issues with destroying and recreating CKEditor 5 instances in my application. Here’s a summary of what I’m trying to achieve and the problems I’m facing:
I need to destroy an existing CKEditor 5 instance when opening a modal and then create a new instance within that modal.
 function initializeEditor() {
    if (window.editorInstance) {
        window.editorInstance.destroy();
    }
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#email_signature_address'), {
            toolbar: ['link'],
            editorConfig: {
                emailMode: true
            }
        })
        .then(editor => {
            window.editorInstance = editor;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('CKEditor initialization error: ', error);
        });
}

$('#createPersonModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   initializeEditor();
});

Problem:

When calling window.editorInstance.destroy(), I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes'). This indicates an issue with destroying the editor instance.
Direct manipulation of the editor’s UI elements (e.g., window.editorInstance.ui.view.element.remove()) does not seem to work


$('#createPersonModal').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();

                initializeEditor();
            });

In my case help this solution. I add off('shown.bs.modal') before 

Ensure that the editorInstance exists before calling the destroy method and the editor is correctly initialized in the modal.
function initializeEditor() {
    if (window.editorInstance) {
        window.editorInstance.destroy()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Editor destroyed successfully.');
                createEditor();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error destroying the editor: ', error);
                createEditor();
            });
    } else {
        createEditor();
    }
}

function createEditor() {
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#email_signature_address'), {
            toolbar: ['link'],
            emailMode: true
        })
        .then(editor => {
            window.editorInstance = editor;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('CKEditor initialization error: ', error);
        });
}

$('#createPersonModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   initializeEditor();
});

